# No URL for ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml] when I run spring-boot with java -jar File.jar

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, apache-tiles

I just move my project from spring 4 to spring-boot-1.5.6-RELEASE and use Apache Tiles in this project. And I get some issue when I run my project with command

> java -jar File.jar

in console show error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in class path resource [/app/spring/configuration/ApplicationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No URL for ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
at com.spt.app.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No URL for ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext.getResources(SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.getSources(TilesConfigurer.java:305)
at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createLocaleDefinitionDao(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:182)
at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(TilesConfigurer.java:353)
at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:86)
at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:114)
at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(TilesConfigurer.java:271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:156)
```

but for

> mvn spring-boot:run

it fine. no problem.

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUmYf.png)

/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml is inside directory resouces/META-INF-/resources. I spend time for this problem 4 days and now I have no idea how I do. Please help me how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: i have same issue when i configure apache tiles 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just packaging with WAR instead of JAR.